# Changing painted image in paint panel

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, drawimage

I'm trying to change the image being painted by sending the new image directory to my paint panel and then changing the Image variable to that image. I've tested the code to make sure that the directories are getting through, but the images never change. They just seem to ignore the new image and keep painting the previous one. I apologize for the messy code but I've been tweaking this for hours trying to get the image to change and the frustration is getting to me.

```
public class painting extends JPanel {
    private String BGDir;
    private String Dir;
    private int Width;
    private int Height;
    private Image image1;
    private Image image2;

    public painting(int h, int w, String BG, String Char) {
        BGDir = BG;
        Dir = Char;
        Height = h;
        Width = w;
        System.out.println(BGDir);
        System.out.println(Dir);
        try {
            image1 = (new ImageIcon(Char)).getImage();
            image2 = (new ImageIcon(BG)).getImage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("no such file");
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public void update(Graphics g) {
        paintComponent(g);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        System.out.println(BGDir);
        System.out.println(Dir);
        // PAINTS THE BACKGROUND
        g2.drawImage(image2, 0, 0, getWidth(), (int) (getWidth() * .533), null);
        // PAINTS THE SCALED CHARACTER
        g2.drawImage(image1, (int) (Width / 6.22), (int) (Height * .246),
                (int) (Height * .754 * .2376), (int) (Height * .754), null);
        repaint();

    }
}
```

Comment: The code seems to be caught in your paragraph of text at the top! I recommend editing so that the whole class is readable.  
 You need to call `repaint()` every time the image is updated, for the record. If you're updating the image outside of this class, you'll need to call repaint() after the new image has been set.

Comment: I'll try that thanks.
I've edited the code to be readable sorry about that
I'm actually just sending the new image data to the painting class through the constructor and then trying to update the image internally because it didn't seem to work when I tried to do it externally

Comment: The problem seems to be that I create a new instance of the painting every time I send the data through the constructors, and that instance isn't added to the JFrame so it isn't displayed. Is there any way of fixing that? I tried removing the JPanel, adding the new one, and then repainting it but it didn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `BufferedImage`, but this is a sample from working code I have.

```
public class PaintPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    BufferedImage icon;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(getBufferedIcon(), 12, 12, null);
    }

    public void setBufferedIcon(BufferedImage icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    private BufferedImage getBufferedIcon() {
        return icon;
    }
}
```

Ignore the offset of 12, that's just because I ripped this from a project of mine. All I do in another class is create the `PaintPanel` and set the `BufferedIcon`.

Every time I wish to update the icon, I call `PaintPanel.setBufferedIcon(icon);` and then `PaintPanel.repaint();`

Remember to *name* the `PaintPanel`, I'm just calling it that so you can read the code easier :)

Comment: This way is much cleaner than the convoluted code I had where I'd create an entirely new JPanel, thank you. I'll try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the images through the constructor parameters after this panel has been instantiated once. You can only create a new instance of this panel (using the new URLs) and afterwards replace the old instance with the new one. You should probably show the code where you create the first instance of this pane, AND the code that shows how you try to update the images.

Comment: I've gotten it to work that way where the image updates by creating a new JPanel and adding it to the JFrame, but the only problem is that it is displayed on top of my UI and the user is unable to interact with the program any more. Is there any way to make a JPanel always displayed on top?